# Android published app not visible in some device's Play Store

Tags: google-play

It's been over eight months since I published my app in the store (mote that 4000 installations), but when i searched it in some device's play store it is not visible.
I tried in two different **Itel devices** and can not find my app when it is visible in other devices.
Help.

Comment: @BianGoole it is called Bracongo

Answer (score 0):

Apps only appear in search results for Google Play when they are compatible with the device. This is to avoid users seeing apps they can't install. This is probably the cause.

If you want to test if this is the cause you can do the following:

- Get a URL for your app in the Play store. You can either do this by looking it up in web browser, or by opening the Play store on a device which does support your app, and choosing "share"
- send an email to an email address you can read on the device. Include the URL you found in step 1 in your email
- click on the URL on the device, and choose to open it in the Play store.

You should go straight to the App, and if it is not compatible with the device you should get a message saying this.